# Is Angry Birds Made Purely Using Bitmaps/Raster graphics?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

Being a beginner game developer I would like to start creating my own engine and graphics so I am concerned about how successful games accomplish the graphics portion.
My question is, are all the graphics (background, birds, slingshot etc) in Angry Birds made with raster images only and using something like a sprite sheet for character animations?

Comment: We usually discourage "How did game X do Y" questions here because, unless the person trying to answer was on the dev team or has reverse-engineered the game themselves, the answer is often "probably Z, but hard to say." It's usually more productive to ask about the thing **you want to do in your game**. After all, if the answer was "Rovio makes all their animations by wishing on a magic lamp" then knowing that wouldn't really help you with your project, would it? ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how a specific game implemented a specific feature.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You were able to see the sprites when Angry Birds Chrome was available to play and they looked like this:

[image]